# Deleting groups that don't appear in every time period and data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, time, rows

I am cleaning data with multiple time periods in each data frame with multiple data frames. Each data frame has one year of data. I want to delete groups that do not appear in each time period(within the data frame), and delete groups that do not appear in each data frame. In other words, I want to keep groups that exist in every time period, across each data frame.  I created data with an ID, time variable, and two variables that represent my data. My data will have more data frames, IDs, groups and variables as well.

```
t<-c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)
id<-c(200,300,200,300,100,200,300,200,300,400)
x1<-rnorm(1:10)
x2<-rnorm(1:10)
?df
df<-data.frame(id,t,x1,x2)
t<-c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4)
id<-c(200,300,400,200,300,200,300,400,200,300)
x1<-rnorm(1:10)
x2<-rnorm(1:10)
df2<-data.frame(id,t,x1,x2)
id<-c(200,300,200,300,600,200,300,100,200,300)
t<-c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4)
x1<-rnorm(1:10)
x2<-rnorm(1:10)
df3<-data.frame(id,t,x1,x2)
rb<-rbind(df,df2,df3)
rb
cb<-cbind(df,df2,df3)
cb
    id t          x1          x2  id t            x1         x2  id t          x1            x2
1  200 1  0.37223136 -0.04918183 200 1  0.6489171399 -0.1324335 200 1 -0.41387676 -0.4566678425
2  300 1 -0.22062416  0.05150952 300 1 -0.3669090613  3.0826144 300 1  0.48237987 -0.0325861333
3  200 2  0.32912208  1.03922999 400 1  0.9347859735  0.1026632 200 2 -0.31308242 -0.3021501845
4  300 2 -0.18172302 -1.41669927 200 2  0.4814364147 -0.1087465 300 2 -1.52273626  0.6357750776
5  100 3 -0.81072008  0.64522238 300 2 -0.5676866296  0.2371230 600 2 -0.09687669  2.2883585934
6  200 3  0.45175343  0.64197622 200 3  0.0006852893  0.5830704 200 3  0.01726120 -0.5905109745
7  300 3  0.40465989 -0.70796588 300 3 -0.0008717189 -1.1969493 300 3 -0.18603781  0.3722390396
8  200 4  0.09852108 -1.76958443 400 3  0.9343534507 -1.3671447 100 4 -0.57308316  0.4749221706
9  300 4 -0.53951022  0.97306346 200 4  1.9176422485  0.9879788 200 4  0.40222133  0.3278821640
10 400 4  0.24271562 -1.37269617 300 4  1.4298971045  1.6095265 300 4  0.85799186  0.0006593401
```

My final out put would look like this:

```
id  t          x1          x2
200 1  0.37223136 -0.04918183 
300 1 -0.22062416  0.05150952
200 2  0.32912208  1.03922999
300 2 -0.18172302 -1.41669927
200 3  0.45175343  0.64197622
300 3  0.40465989 -0.70796588
200 4  0.09852108 -1.76958443
300 4 -0.53951022  0.97306346
200 1  0.6489171399 -0.1324335
300 1 -0.3669090613  3.0826144
200 2  0.4814364147 -0.1087465
300 2 -0.5676866296  0.2371230
200 3  0.0006852893  0.5830704
300 3 -0.0008717189 -1.1969493
200 4  1.9176422485  0.9879788
300 4  1.4298971045  1.6095265
200 1 -0.41387676 -0.4566678425
300 1  0.48237987 -0.0325861333
200 2 -0.31308242 -0.3021501845
300 2 -1.52273626  0.6357750776
200 3  0.01726120 -0.5905109745
300 3 -0.18603781  0.3722390396
200 4  0.40222133  0.3278821640
300 4  0.85799186  0.0006593401
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One strategy is to count the number of times each combination of `id` and `t` appears.  If this is equals the maximum possible, then keep that id.  (I used `max` to get the maximum possible combinations, but that only works if at least one `id` has appeared in every `t`.

I use `adply` from the `plyr` package here to replace your `rbind` step, because `adply` preserves information about which data frame each row came from (in the `X1` column).

```
library(plyr)
rb <- adply(list(df, df2, df3), 1)

unique_combo <- unique(rb[, c("X1", "id", "t")])
##    X1  id t
## 1   1 200 1
## 2   1 300 1
## 3   1 200 2
## 4   1 300 2
## 5   1 100 3
## 6   1 200 3
## 7   1 300 3
## 8   1 200 4
## 9   1 300 4
## 10  1 400 4
## 11  2 200 1
## 12  2 300 1 etc.

combos_per_id <- aggregate(t ~ id, FUN = length, data = unique_combo)
##    id  t
## 1 100  2
## 2 200 12
## 3 300 12
## 4 400  3
## 5 600  1

ids_you_want <- subset(combos_per_id, t == max(t))
##    id  t
## 2 200 12
## 3 300 12

rb[rb$id %in% ids_you_want$id, ]
##    X1  id t          x1           x2
## 1   1 200 1  0.41800060 -0.729280896
## 2   1 300 1 -1.26310444  0.649438361
## 3   1 200 2  1.75130801  0.340464369
## 4   1 300 2 -0.47751518 -1.396611139
## 6   1 200 3 -0.11537438 -1.483654622
## 7   1 300 3 -1.33689508 -1.219725112 etc.
```

**Edit** to handle another column

```
library(plyr)
t<-c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)
id<-c(200,300,200,300,100,200,300,200,300,400)
x1<-rnorm(1:10)
x2<-rnorm(1:10)
r<-c("b","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a")
df<-data.frame(id,t,x1,x2, r)

t<-c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4)
id<-c(200,300,400,200,300,200,300,400,200,300)
x1<-rnorm(1:10)
x2<-rnorm(1:10)
r<-c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a")
df2<-data.frame(id,t,x1,x2, r)

id<-c(200,300,200,300,600,200,300,100,200,300)
t<-c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4)
x1<-rnorm(1:10)
x2<-rnorm(1:10)
r<-c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a")
df3<-data.frame(id,t,x1,x2, r)

rb <- adply(list(df, df2, df3), 1)
unique_combo <- unique(rb[, c("X1", "id", "t", "r")])
(combos_per_id <- aggregate(t ~ id + r, FUN = length, data = unique_combo))
ids_you_want <- subset(combos_per_id, t == max(t))
rb[rb$id %in% ids_you_want$id, ]
```

Comment: How would I do this is if there was another column that I wanted to use to delete ids? For example if there where a column 'r<-c("b","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a")','r<-c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a")','r<-c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a")'. If I only wanted to keep those ids that exist in every time period and every character? In this example only id300 would show up in the final data, since it appears in every time period and has at least one character that follows it through each time period.

Comment: Add the `r` column to the `unique` function call, and use `t ~ id + r` in the `aggregate` function call.

Comment: Thank you, but when I tried this it kept id200. I don't want to keep id200, since only had the letter "b" corresponding to one period.  With the data I posted id300 has the letter "a" corresponding to the id in every period. I was thinking I might need to use something similar to: 'ids_you_want <- subset(combos_per_id, t == max(t) & r==max(r))'

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit brute force, but should work:

```
frames <- list(df,df2,df3)

lu <- function(x)
    length(unique(x))

timePeriodsPerDataframe <- sapply(frames,function(x)lu(x))

for(i in seq(length(frames))){
    appearsInEveryTimePeriod <- tapply(frames[[i]]$id,
                                       frames[[i]]$t,
                                       lu) == timePeriodsPerDataframe[i]
    if(i == 1)
        IDsInEveryTimePeriod <- names(tmp[tmp])
    else
        IDsInEveryTimePeriod <- intersect(names(tmp[tmp]),IDsInEveryTimePeriod)
}
IDsInEveryTimePeriod <- as.numeric(IDsInEveryTimePeriod)
```